# Image Not Appearing on Webpage

Tags: html, image

I am in the final steps of testing my page before I make it public. I have an issue with the image on my main page showing up. It looks like a broken link but I am not sure why it's not showing up. All of my other pages multimedia links are working fine. The image in question is Beer.jpg.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- The Homebrewery
        Author: Chris Stastny
        Date: October 27th, 2015
    -->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Homebrewery - Homebrewing</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The Homebrewery - Homebrewing">
  <meta name="author" content="Chris Stastny">
 <link href="final.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
 <script src="beerStyle.js"></script>

 </head>
 <header>
  <h1> The Homebrewery</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="About.htm">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Equipment.htm">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="BrewLog.htm">Brew Log</a></li>
        <li><a href="Links.htm">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="Newsletter.htm">Newsletter</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>
  <h2>Greetings!</h2>

    <div id="dateBox">
        Today's Beer Style is: 
       <script>
  document.getElementById("dateBox").innerHTML+=style[new Date().getUTCDate()];
        </script> 
    </div>   
   <br>   
   <img src="Beer.jpg" alt="beer" />

  <p>This website was built to keep people informed about my homebrewing adventures. It will have brewday pictures, videos (possibly) in the future, recipes and general homebrewing information. There is also a newsletter that you can sign up for that will go into more detail about what is going on with my brewing.</p>

   <br>
   <footer>The Homebrewery - Homebrewing - 2015</footer>  

</body> 


</html>
```

Comment: double check to make sure the image is in the same folder as your html and double check spelling ?

Comment: Try this `<img src="beer.jpg" alt="">` and write your image name in small letters.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. Either the image exists on the server or it doesn't, and if it does then you probably have the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:
-image is in the same folder
-the image is called Beer.jpg and not beer.jpg
-open again the file in your ftp folder and check if it's the same with what you've posted here